# Ftp File Upload

Tags: c++, ftp

```
BOOL uploadFile(char *filename, char *destination_name, char *address, char *username, char *password)
{
    BOOL t = false;
    HINTERNET hint, hftp;
    hint = InternetOpen("FTP", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    hftp = InternetConnect(hint, address, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, username, password, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0 , 0);
    t = FtpPutFile(hftp, filename, destination_name, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);
    return t;
}
```

This is my function to uploading file to server, it is good written ?
And i am using in function

```
uploadFile(workFullPath,extractFilename(workFullPath),"address","login","password");
```

But my file does not appears on ftp.

Comment: You test none of the return values for success. Hard to say what went wrong or where without checking the results.

Comment: I was doing GetlastError buts return of this was very huge randomly value, thats was weird

Comment: `GetLastError` is the right thing to look at, but it's only really useful after the first error. After that, Crom only knows what's happened. For example, say `InternetOpen` returns `NULL`. Calling `InternetConnect` with `NULL` could result in problems that may not be able to set GetLastError to a meaningful value.  And if `InternetConnect` fails, `FtpPutFile` could do something else weird. Check the return values early and often. Don't use a returned value until after you know it is safe to use.

Comment: Thanks for advice i will check it

Comment: Got dragged for a few minutes away there. What you want to do is call `InternetOpen`, then test `hint`. If `hint` is `NULL`, use `GetLastError` to find out why and make corrections or give up on connecting. If `hint` is OK, call `InternetConnect` and test `hftp`... Repeat until done.

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing any error handling at all, so you have no way of knowing why the file does not get uploaded.

Whenever a WinInet functions fails, you can call [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) to find out why it failed, per the WinInet documentation for each function.

If `GetLastError()` returns [`ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465.aspx), use [`InternetGetLastResponseInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384717.aspx) to get the server's error:

> ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR
>   12003
>   An extended error was returned from the server. This is typically a string or buffer containing a verbose error message. Call `InternetGetLastResponseInfo` to retrieve the error text.

See WinInet's [Handling Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383884.aspx) documentation for an example of using `InternetGetLastResponseInfo()`.

Something else to pay attention to - you are calling `InternetOpen()` with the `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` flag:

> Makes only asynchronous requests on handles descended from the handle returned from this function.

But, you are not actually using WinInet asynchronously, so you should not be using that flag at all.

See WinInet's [FTP Sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180.aspx) documentation for more details about how to use the WinInet FTP functions.

Try something more like this instead:

```
BOOL uploadFile(char *filename, char *destination_name, char *address, char *username, char *password)
{
    BOOL res = FALSE;
    DWORD err;

    HINTERNET hint = InternetOpen("FTP", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0);
    if (hint == NULL)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        // handle the error as needed...
        goto done;
    }

    HINTERNET hftp = InternetConnect(hint, address, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, username, password, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0 , 0);
    if (hftp == NULL)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        // handle the error as needed...
        goto cleanup;
    }

    res = FtpPutFile(hftp, filename, destination_name, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    if (!res)
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        // handle the error as needed...
    }

cleanup:
    if (hftp) InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    if (hint) InternetCloseHandle(hint);

done:
    return res;
}
```